# Запуск проекта с DevExpress на другом ПК

Tags: c#, windows, devexpress

Всем добрый день! У меня проект, WinForms вместе с DevExpress. В своем компьютере без проблем и хорошо работает (и в нем было собран и устанавливал компоненты, все нормально). А в другом ПК вообще не запускается и не работает. Пытаюсь решить проблему, но никак мне не помогло... Все ссылки подключены, и где *.exe есть файлы DevExpress *.dll
P.S. Помогите пожалуйста, не могу дальше что-то делать...

Comment: Знаете что такое логирование? Вот оно вам и нужно. Сделайте перехват всех исключений (В WinForms это вроде UnhandledException), ну и смотрите что именно вызывает проблему. А сообщество SO в этом вопросе, без данных, будет только гадать...

Comment: Ошибки никаких не выдает, просто проект на запускается и все... Пробовал и в режиме "Запустить от имени администратора", тоже и такой результат

Comment: Не все ошибки изначально отображаются (например отсутствие DLL...). Я вам уже сказал, отловите все необработанные исключения (вот на [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762526/how-can-i-make-something-that-catches-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-a-winforms-a) вариант (но не уверен, с WinForms уже давно не общался)), выведите их например в файл или сообщением и глядите что конкретно от вас просит программа! Программа не может просто так закрываться, она закрывается либо если вы это сами прописали, либо ошибки!